# Cassandra Cql schema best practice

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql3, cqlsh, cassandra-jdbc

Here I am again asking similar question after getting really a great explanation on 
[How do secondary indexes work in Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692738/how-secondary-indexes-works-in-cassandra/29701067#29701067)

```
CREATE TABLE update_audit (
  scopeid bigint,
  formid bigint,
  time timestamp,
  operation int,
  record_id bigint,
  ipaddress text,
  user_id bigint,
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((scopeid), formid, time)
  ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (formid ASC, time DESC)
```

FYI,
**operation** Column possible values are  1,2 and 3. Low cardinality.

**record_link_id** high-cardinality. every entry can be unique.

**user_id** is the best candidate for Index according to [How do secondary indexes work in Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692738/how-secondary-indexes-works-in-cassandra/29701067#29701067) and [The sweet spot for cassandra secondary indexing.](http://www.wentnet.com/blog/?p=77)

Search should work based on

- **time** with limit 100.
- **operation** and **time** with limit 100.
- **user_id** and **time** with limit 100.
- **record_id** and time with limit 100.

**Problems**

total records more than 10,000M

which One is best
 - **creating Index over operation**, **user_id** and **record_id** and applying limit 100.

```
  1) Does Hidden columnfamily for index operation Will return only 100 results?

  2) More seeks will slow down the fetch operation?
```

**OR** Create a new columnfamily with definition like

```
CREATE TABLE audit_operation_idx (
  scopeid bigint,
  formid bigint,
  operation int,
  time timeuuid,
  PRIMARY KEY ((scopeid), formid, operation, time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (formid ASC, operation ASC, time DESC) 

 required two select query for single select operation.
```

So, if I will create new columnfamily for **operation**, **user_id** and **record_id**

I have to make a batch query to insert into these four columnfamilies.

```
   3) Does TCP problems will come? while executing batch query.because writes will be huge. 
   4) what else should I cover to avoid unnecessary problems.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three options.

1. Create a new table and use bulk insert. If the size of insert query becomes huge you'll have to configure its related parameter. Don't worry about writes in Cassandra.
2. Create a materialized View with required columns of where clause.
3. Create secondary index if cardinality  is low. (Not recommended)